# Can I remove origin/master merge history without removing recently commits?

Tags: git, github, merge

I branched off of `master` to `branch2`, made some changes, and made a commit. When I push, I see that any new pull review that I make will have a bunch of commits like

```
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:repo/name
...
My actual commit message here
```

Is it possible to rebase while keeping my real commit?

Comment: "Is it possible to rebase while keeping my real commit?" Absolutely, it's quite standard to rebase your branch just before pushing, exactly so that you move the _merge base_ up to the very end of `master`. Did you try it? Of course, it's a little late now; if you rebase at this point, you will have to _force_ push your branch. The time to think of this is _before_ pushing. But the force push will probably do no harm.

Comment: You mentioned that you "made some changes", and also "made a commit". Did you also merge `master` into your branch 6 times?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one working on that PR branch, it is not too late to rebase it, and force push it:

```
git fetch
git switch branch2
git rebase origin/master
# check everything still work(!)
git push --force
```